# Text and variables in Tkinter lable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a times tables testing app, in which two numbers are randomly generated and the user is then asked to type in the answer. The problem is that when I try to get the variables to appear on a label alongside some text:

```
from random import randint
import Tkinter as tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('Times Tables')
a = randint(1, 12)
b = randint(1, 12)
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is",a,"+",b, "?")
lbl.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Then I get this error message:

```
Tkinter GUI/gui.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
  File "/Users/teymouraldridge/Desktop/Code/Python/Tkinter GUI/gui.py", line 7
    lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is",a,"+",b, "?")
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword ar
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user attempted to delete it anyway by erasing the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is",a,"+",b, "?")
```

the `text=` named argument wants a string, but you passed the string `"What is"` followed by what look like additional positional arguments to Python.  You can't use comma's to build up your string.  You can go the hard way:

```
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is " + str(a) + " + " + str(b) + "?")
```

Or you could use the Python2-style % format operator or the newer Python 3 `.format()` method of `str` which has been also backported to Python 2.7:

```
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is {} + {}?".format(a, b))
```

Either way, the `text=` argument has to be passed a single, finished string.